# Delete pcap file after parsing it with PcapReader in scapy

Tags: python-2.7, scapy, pcap

I'm parsing a pcap file with PcapReader in scapy. After that I want to delete the pcap file. But it sucks because of this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 26] Text file busy: '/media/sf_SharedFolder/AVB/test.pcap'
```

This is my python code:

```
from scapy.all import *
import os

var = []

for packet in PcapReader('/media/sf_SharedFolder/AVB/test.pcap'):
  var.append(packet[Ether].src)

os.remove('/media/sf_SharedFolder/AVB/test.pcap')
```

I think that this error occurs with any pcap file.

Does somebody has any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try with Scapy's latest development version (from https://github.com/secdev/scapy), since I cannot reproduce your issue with it.

If that does not work, check with `lsof /media/sf_SharedFolder/AVB/test.pcap` (as root) if another program has opened your capture file. If so, try to find (and kill, if possible) that program.

You can try two different hacks, to try to figure out what exactly is happening:

Test 1: wait.

```
from scapy.all import *
import os
import time

var = []

for packet in PcapReader('/media/sf_SharedFolder/AVB/test.pcap'):
    var.append(packet[Ether].src)

time.sleep(2)
os.remove('/media/sf_SharedFolder/AVB/test.pcap')
```

Test 2: explicitly close.

```
from scapy.all import *
import os

var = []

pktgen = PcapReader('/media/sf_SharedFolder/AVB/test.pcap')
for packet in pktgen:
    var.append(packet[Ether].src)

pktgen.close()
os.remove('/media/sf_SharedFolder/AVB/test.pcap')
```

Comment: scapy version is 2.3.3.dev862. lsof says, that python and sh are working with the file.

Comment: What is that sh process? Have you checked that the python process is the one running your script? You can add `print(os.getpid(), os.getppid())` to your script's code to get its PID and its parent's PID.

Comment: "lsof" says that the script runs with the process "python" (PID 1425) and process "sh" (PID 1428). The PID of the script is 1425, parents PID is 1404.

Comment: OK so you need to find what is the 1428, because it might be the process responsible for this error. `ps -ef | grep 1428` to get its command line?

Comment: "lsof" gives me the PID of the process "sh". But how should I write the code, so that the command "ps -ef | grep PID_of_sh" uses the PID of the process "sh"? Something like "foo = second PID of lsof test.pcap" and then "ps -ef | grep foo".

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I replaced "PcapReader()" through "rdpcap()". Seems like PcapReader is open until the python script is finished.

This is the working code:

```
from scapy.all import *
import os

var = []

p=rdpcap('/media/sf_SharedFolder/AVB/test.pcap')

for packet in p:
  var.append(packet[Ether].src)

os.remove('/media/sf_SharedFolder/AVB/test.pcap')
```

Comment: This works, but please note that if your PCAP file is large, you may exhaust your memory (and hence be unable to process large files)